# Kill APscheduler add_job based on id

Tags: flask, process, grep, pid, apscheduler

We have a flask script `get_logs.py` that uses `APScheduler` and contains following job

```
scheduler.add_job(id="create_recommendation_entries", trigger = 'interval',seconds=60*10,func=create_entries)
```

Someone ran the script and now the the logs show that this script is still running at 10 minutes interval even after terminating.

The process id is not listed nor does it show using grep and we don't know whether it was executed using nohup or gunicorn.

How do I kill this job based on `id="create_recommendation_entries"`because I don't know any of its stats(port,pid etc).
Rerunning the script creates a different thread and stops after Ctrl+C but the previous one remains still in process
[image: Logs after 10 minute]

Comment: what jobstore are you using? A hacky way would be to manually delete the job from the jobstore, then restart your app to refresh the jobstore...

Comment: @sur.la.route How does one do that? Jobstore was default. I tried running the .py file again and added a `remove_job(jobstore=Deafult)` or `remove_all_jobs(jobstore=Default)` but no result. I think what running the .py again does is runs and deletes the jobs of the jobstore that was created while running the file again but the previous one remains the same.

Comment: Well, when anything changes in the scheduler it rechecks everything in the jobstore. Maybe try to add a job, and then delete all jobs at the same script run? What is your jobstore? redis/sqlite/? Can you manually query the table and see what is in it?

Comment: You can try [simple-scheduler](https://pypi.org/project/simple_scheduler/). It shows the pid to which the task was assigned through job_summary() attribute